# JSON: Object to JsonString - JsonString to X.class Object

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, java-ee-7

I've got a class called `MediaList` and I want to parse this class with values to a JSON-String and backwards.

```
public class KeywordList {
       private List<Keyword> keywords = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And here the JSON-String:

```
{
    "keywords": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Thesis",
            "mediaCount": 31
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

I'm using google lib *gson*, but i just want to use the standard java version with jax-rs because i don't want 3rd party tools to be in my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to use external libraries cause Java by default can't do this.

Although that may change with `Java 9` but looking from the changes i haven't seen something for build in JSON Library . I heard but i haven't seen it inside.

You can see [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/) all the new features of Java 9.

You will find what libraries you may need , along with tutorials [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-json-tutorials/)

Until it exists we have the amazing [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) Library:

1.1 Convert Java object to JSON, writeValue(...)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Staff obj = new Staff();

//Object to JSON in file
mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\file.json"), obj);

//Object to JSON in String
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
```

1.2 Convert JSON to Java object, readValue(...)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'mkyong'}";

//JSON from file to Object
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\file.json"), Staff.class);

//JSON from URL to Object
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://mkyong.com/api/staff.json"), Staff.class);

//JSON from String to Object
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Staff.class);
```

Where `Staff` is:

```
 import java.math.BigDecimal;    import java.util.List;
 public class Staff { 
     private String name; 
     private int age; 
     private String position; 
    private BigDecimal salary; 
    private List<String> skills; 
    //getters and setters 
}
```

Complete tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)

Comment: Jackson lib is great. Definitely my preferred JSON library

Answer (score 1):

The JDK itself doesn't contain an implementation of the JAX-RS standard, so you'll have to use a third party library in any case.